# How do I prove the following about SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $$C = \sum_{i=1}^d x_i y_i^{\top}$$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{10 \times 1}$ and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^{20 \times 1}$ (so $C$ is a sum of outer products.)

I now apply an (thin) SVD on $C$ (which I know is of rank $d$ at most, $d<10$), so I get $U \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times 10}$.

How do I show that for any $z$ linear combination of the $x_i$ vectors it holds that

$$U^{\top} U z = z ?$$

Comment: Isn't that just a convention that is taken by definition during the SVD? Besides knowing that they are eigenvectors of $CC^T$ or $C^TC$ and therefore orthogonal, you have a freedom in choosing the columns of $U$ and $V$. That you pick them ortho**normal**, which is equivalent to your question, is just a matter of choice.

Comment: $U^{\top}U$ doesnt have to be the identity because it is thin-SVD... if it were thin-SVD, then yes. @TheVee